# Date formats in C#

Tags: c#

I need to display dates in Month date, year (Ex: January 20, 2010).

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var dt = new DateTime(2010, 20, 1);
string s = dt.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy");
```

[See here for more info.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

See this MSDN document. Contains all the information required for custom date and time format strings.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Probably worth bookmarking it as well, I always find myself coming back to it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.Format(formatspecifier)`

[Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try `DateField.ToString("MMMM-dd-yyyy");`